# MVC - Select from Stored Procedure in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

I am new to ASP.NET MVC. I should create a page where users enters an order for their shops by central warehouse. The products and amounts are listed by a stored procedure from database. I have to show rows in a gridview which are calculated by the stored procedure. I want to insert the changed data in a table in SQL after the user make changes on the gridview. Users can call the saved doc back and make changes on it and save it again.

I can't build a strategy how that can be made. If I use Entity Framework I can show the SQL table rows in grid but it is not my goal. I have to let the SQL calculate first the data. Could you please give me some start point and steps to go ahead. I hope I could explain what I need.

Answer (score 0):

There Are some simple steps to do that

1- Go and update model from database and add the required Stored procedure[image]

2- create a complex type from model browser

[image]

in complex type map your Stored procedure fields as it returns the data.

3- and map that complex type to the stored procedure. and use it as you use table.

Comment: Great explanation thanks for the answer but one more question; the data come from stored procedure into the complex type and that is my datasource in gridview but how can I update or insert the needed column values into another table which I wish?

Comment: if you want,you can write an Stored procedure for saving the data,which will accept the updated field as input. Or if you have a table for that where you wanna save data you can create a object of respective  table named class created by EF, and fill all the details. Like `UpdatedData dt=new UpdatedData();`` dt.txt="whatever updated data you are getting from dataGrid";``_db.Add(dt);``_db.saveChange()`

Comment: @Haloki Hope above explanation and this [Link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application) will help you - thanks.

Comment: ;) very nice. I will try it now. I hope I can make it. @Viplock +1